# Is it deliver or have delivered by tonight?

Tags: present-perfect, infinitives, present-simple

> Can you deliver it by tonight?

Or

> Can you have delivered it by tonight?

What sounds more natural? Which of the two sentences is incorrect?

Comment: The first would be more natural when making a direct request (you ask someone to do something, not to have already done it). But you could say "I hope they will have delivered it by tonight" (because that is when it will be needed, so you hope it will already be there).

Comment: You could also say 'Can you have it delivered by tonight?' (causative style) depending on the context.